# Accessing the real file name of a symbolic linked file

Tags: ruby, filenames, symlink

When a file is loaded/required via a symbolic link, all the methods, keywords, etc. that refer to a file name seem to refer to the link name, and not the real file name. For example, suppose I have a file `foo.rb` with its contents something like:

```
puts __FILE__, __dir__, caller
```

and a symbolic link `bar.rb` pointing to `foo.rb`. If I load/require `foo.rb` via the symbolic link `bar.rb`, then all of the file names given by the commands above describe the symbolic link name `bar.rb`, and not the real file name `foo.rb`.

Is there a way to call the counterparts of `__FILE__`, `__dir__`, `caller`, etc. with the file names pointing to the real file and not the symbolic link names?

Comment: How do you define "real", I ask you? Your "real" file name is just an entry in FS metadata that points to certain location on disk. So is symlink. The same data can be addressed by many names. How do you pick one "real"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Maybe my usage of the word "real" may not have been appropriate, but you seem to know what I mean. And there is a certain difference between symbolic links and what I call real files.

Comment: My limited knowledge of OS and filesystems says it can't be done. Filename is filename. I might be wrong, of course.

Comment: Do you care about hardlinks? Those are more files than symlinks are.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I didn't think about that. I actually only need to care when there is only one (original) hardlink per file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could not change all those constants and built-ins so easily, but you can do this:

```
File.realpath( "/path/to/file/or/symlink" )
```

or

```
require 'pathname'
Pathname.new( "/path/to/file/or/symlink" ).realpath
```

Example file *realfile.rb*

```
names = [ __FILE__, __dir__]
p names
p names.map { |name| File.realpath(name) }
```

Set up and called like this:

```
ln -s realfile.rb thelinkfile
ruby thelinkfile
```

Output:

```
["thelinkfile", "/Users/neilslater/scraps"]
["/Users/neilslater/scraps/realfile.rb", "/Users/neilslater/scraps"]
```

Comment: You can also use the core `require File.realpath('...')` instead of `Pathname`.

Comment: @koffeinfrei: Thanks, I think I prefer `File.realpath`, so added to answer