# Guard Ruby classes with class-level metaprogramming against multiple loads

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, require

A quirk of Ruby's `require` is that, while in general, it will only load a file once, if that file is accessible via multiple paths (e.g. symlinks), it can be `required` multiple times. This causes problems when there are things like class-level metaprogramming, or in general a code that should only be executed once on file loading, getting executed multiple times.

Is there any way, from **inside** a Ruby class definition, to tell whether the class has been defined before? I thought `defined?` or `Object.const_get` might tell me, but from those it looks like the class is defined as soon as it's opened.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking in the second paragraph is a solution to the issue in your first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question in the second paragraph, but a solution to the issue in your first paragraph. Actually, you cannot avoid multiple file loads by checking whether a class was defined already.

Instead of doing:

```
require some_file_name
```

do:

```
require File.realpath(some_file_name)
```

By doing so, different symbolic links pointing to the same real file would be normalized to the same real file name, and hence multiple loading of them would be correctly filtered by `require`.

Cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935615/accessing-the-real-file-name-of-a-symbolic-linked-file) and the answer given there.

Answer (score 0):

The *real* solution is that requiring that a piece of code is only executed once is bad design and you should fix that.

However, what you *could* do is simply set some flag that the code has already been executed and check that flag. E.g.:

```
class Foo
  unless @__executed__
    def bla; end
    puts 'Test'
  end
  @__executed__ = true
end
```